# How to receive and process json objects in cakephp?

Tags: jquery, json, cakephp, cordova

I am developing an app using phonegap for Android. I want this mobile application to send some data (mostly text) to an external server backed by cakephp, using jquery and json objects.

I am relatively new to cakephp and the MVC structure, and would appreciate some general advice on how to proceed with this in cake. I basically want phonegap to send formdata to the cakeapplication, and have cake save this data to the database. This is the code I am thinking about using for sending data in phonegap:

HTML form:

```
    <form method="post" id="infoForm">
       <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" value="" placeholder="First Name"  />
       <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" value="" placeholder="Last Name"  />   
       <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" placeholder="Email"  />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button> 
</form>
```

Jquery:

```
$('#infoForm').submit(function() {

    var postTo = '//url to cakeapplication';

    $.post(postTo,({first_name: $('[name=first_name]').val(), last_name: $('[name=last_name]').val(), email: $('[name=email]').val()}),
    function(data) {
        alert(data);
        if(data != "") {
            // do something
        } else {
            // couldn't connect
        }        
        },'json');
    return false;
});
```

Can anyone provde som general instructions on how process this data in cake?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP5 has the [`json_encode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [`json_decode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) functions which are of great use. If you're stuck on PHP4 I believe there's a [JSON Compenent](https://github.com/meeech/json-component-cakephp-plugin) for Cake. I can't say much about the latter, but calling the PHP5 `json_decode()` will result in a PHP object which you can use to construct a Cake data array to be saved in the database.

What you want is to have your AJAX function call a method (`add()` for example) in the Cake controller which handles saving data to your database. Cake's `save` method expects a specially formatted array, the structure of it [is detailed here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1031/Saving-Your-Data), so you'll have to manually construct this yourself.

Say your modelised database table for PhoneGap data is called "Phonegap" (in that case you would have a `PhonegapModel` and `PhonegapsController`). The data array for saving would have the following structure:

```
function add() {
  $this->data = array(
    'Phonegap' => array(
      'first_name' => 'value',
      'last_name' => 'value',
      'email' => 'value'
    )
  );
  $this->Phonegap->save($this->data);
}
```

The JSON object is probably available via `$this->params['form']` (as per [here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/963/The-Parameters-Attribute-params)) in the controller, as you're performing an AJAX post. I'm not entirely sure how much you already know about CakePHP, so if some things need clarification, just let me know.

Comment: I am pretty new to cake, but I think I am able to understand (almost) everything you wrote. Really appreciate your answer! It gives me something to start with!